# Parsing an api response

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, get, fetch-api

I want to parse this api response to get the image url and I find it a little confusing actually because I'm new with apis.

```
    {
      "id": "123",
      "item": [
        {
          "picture": {
            "type_id": "2",
            "url": [
              "./img.jpg"
            ],
            "is_in_description": 0,
            "gallery": {
              "url": "",
              "url_id": ""
            },
            "layout_id": "2",
            "variation_name": ""
          },
          "lister_id": "12345"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here is my code for fetching the api, can anyone help me with that

```
fetch(url2,{
          method: 'GET'
        })
        .then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          const newImg = responseJson.item.map( => {
            return{
              const img = 
            };
          })
          const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
            items: newItems
          });

          console.log(newState);
          this.setState(newState);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        });
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what parsing response.You can directly access `url` property of each element in item array by parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `map` method for parsing as

```
var x =   {
      "id": "123",
      "item": [
        {
          "picture": {
            "type_id": "2",
            "url": [
              "./img.jpg"
            ],
            "is_in_description": 0,
            "gallery": {
              "url": "",
              "url_id": ""
            },
            "layout_id": "2",
            "variation_name": ""
          },
          "lister_id": "12345"
        }
      ]
    }

x.item.map(data=>{console.log(data.picture.url)}) //hope you need the url object
```